# Recursive quick sort in python

Tags: python, quick-sort

I was wondering if there is anything that I could do to make my code look cleaner and more descriptive for educational purposes?

```py
def quick_sort(array, start, end):
    if start < end:
        pivot_index = partition(array, start, end)
        quick_sort(array, start, pivot_index - 1)
        quick_sort(array, pivot_index + 1, end)


def partition(array, start, end):
    pivot_index = start
    pivot = array[end]
    for loop_index in range(start, end):
        if array[loop_index] <= pivot:
            array[pivot_index], array[loop_index] = array[loop_index], array[pivot_index]
            pivot_index += 1
    array[pivot_index], array[end] = array[end], array[pivot_index]
    return pivot_index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you want your code cleaner and more descriptive, try adding some English text somewhere. I usually find docstrings are the right place to start in python. What does `partition` do? What does `quick_sort` do? In general by "what does X do?", I mean what does it take in as input, and what does it return--the reader of a docstring doesn't care what happens in between. Read the standard library function descriptions for nice examples.
- Right now there is no clear entry point--`quick_sort` takes in three values, which is not what a user would like. Add a function which takes in an array and returns the sorted array. You could either add a new function, or default values for the extra two arguments of `quick_sort`. Both are common.

Answer (score 1):

Code is clear and straight forward to read. However, there are two assumptions here

1. It will be used with data types for which "<=" operation is defined. It is good idea to extract this part comparator and let caller decide how two members should be compared.
2. array[end] is always good pivot. This may not be always true. Good pivot is critical for quick sort effectiveness. Input randomisation is commonly used to make good pivot selection more probable.

Comment: Could you expand on what "Input randomisation" is. I've not come across this before and don't understand what you mean by your answer as is. I feel I could learn something here, but I'm just not able to connect the dots.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Here, [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomization_function#Uses) might help you.